# How to fix width of column in two-column CSS lay out?

Tags: css, layout

I'm having problems getting several divs to function as two columns. In the code below I want the `container` (or `content`) and `right` to act as two columns.

- Both **need** borders (non-image) where the border in between both should be the same visual width as the outer borders.
- Both columns need to have the same height between `top` and `bottom`
- `right` should be fixed size

Is this even possible without changing the HTML?

Take the following HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="top"></div>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="right">
  </div>

  <div id="bottom"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Whatever did happen to tables? I miss them... Everything was so easy back then... To answer your question: I don't think it's possible without dirty CSS/HTML 'hacks'. I'm pretty sure Sitepoint's Tech Times did an article on this a short while ago tho... [...] (I can't find it.)

Comment: why have you got right div, nested outside of container div ?

Comment: Sorry the HTML cannot change...

Comment: Post an image of your exact requirements

Comment: Post your css, then more people can help. Just posting html, which you then say, cannot change is hardly useful is it

Comment: I understand. What I did was span `container` over the entire width of the page with a right and left border. `content` now acts as a left column while I then hover the `right` div to act as a right column. Not very charming but hey it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want.

Markup

```
<body>
    <div id="top">top</div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            content
         </div>
         <div id="right">
            right
         </div>
         <br style="clear:both" />
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#container {border:1px solid blue;}
#content, #right {float:left;}
#content {width:400px; border-right:1px solid blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt anser your issue fully, as your question is a tad lightweight, but you can position divs however you want. Fiddle here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ozzy/F3K8k/

Have updated fiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ozzy/F3K8k/1/

Comment: Thanks for the input, but no-can-do

Comment: Y No-Kan-do ? change the markup and elements to fit your needs, simple stuff really